# Visual Studio & TortoiseSVN

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn

We have 3 VS2008 projects. Each project builds a executable and supporting files. All 3 projects will eventually ship together as an application.

Up till now we have been using a separate SVN repository for each project and managing them separately  with TortoiseSVN.  At this stage it is now becoming necessary to share files between the different projects.

Should we create a new VS Solution, add the projects to it and then create a new repository?  Not sure if this is the right approach and am looking for advice. Also need to retains the different version and commit logs for the 3 projects.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep them separate, you can use svn:externals to import pieces of one project into another and continue to manage them separately.

Comment: I have svn:externals working now thanks. This seemed the best option - Out of interest If I was starting afresh with 3 projects again what's the recommended way to set these up in visual studio and SVN? Adding the 3 projects to one solution makes sense but should I then create one single repository for the 3 projects?

Comment: I work with a single repository and I have quite a bit of projects. I think you should create a different repository only for projects that are mostly unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share files between those projects, it will be easier to have them in the same repository. They can then share the same history and can be branched, merged etc.

In principle, you can create a dump from one repository and import this into the other one. I have, however, never tried this with a live repository. You might want to test this first.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) each repository and [load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) them all into a single repository.  The change logs will be preserved, but new revision numbers will be assigned.  I have not done this myself, but someone has done it on a project I was working on and it went smoothly.